# How to import an entire folder in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to import an entire folder of icons in react.What is the correct way to do that. Actually I am fetching data from an API so based on that data I wish to generate some icons which are all stored in some folder.What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: doesn't matter what backend I have ..and have tried drawing the entire folder but I don't know how to reference each icon

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you can do 2 things import the static way or import dynamically

The static way is like the following:

```
import as icons from '../icons';
// This way you have a reference of the entire folder
// and when referencing each icon I think you can accessed if like it was an object
```

*I have never do this method before (of bringin the hole folder) so you can try a console log of the icons reference like console.log(icons); and see what is returning*

The dynamic way is like so :

```
 // in the function that executes which icon is going to be displayed
 // based on the response returned from the api you can do this
if(randomApi === "randomResponse")  {
   import('./icons/icon1').then(icon => {
     this.setState({ iconToDisplay: icon });   
  })
} else if (randomApi2 === "randomResponse2") {
  import('./icons/icon2').then(icon => {
     this.setState({ iconToDisplay: icon });   
  })
```

}

Something like that

Further reading:

https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports

### *NOTE*: That you will be have to install an extra dependency like a polyfill in order to support old browsers